# Breakpoints in expression / template code in Plone

Tags: plone

If you have a situation where a TAL expression doesn't work (example below):

```
context.restrictedTraverse('@@contenthistory').fullHistory()[0]['comments']
```

What options there exist to debug this situation. Namely, can one put breakpoints to

- TAL templates
- TAL expression
- Any expressions (e.g. portal_actions)

Comment: More info: https://github.com/collective/collective.developermanual/issues/174

Comment: Nope, there are no debugging tools available for TAL apart from breaking it down to constituent parts and 'printing' the values.

Comment: That particular expression doesn't work because of a "not authorised" exception in "context.restrictedTraverse('@@contenthistory')". turning on verbose-security doesn't give any more information as to why.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Chameleon (you should!) you can use this:

```
<?python import pdb; pdb.set_trace() ?>
```

The stuff you normally look for is accessible in 'econtext':

```
econtext['context']
econtext['request']
```

Comment: You are using Chameleon with Plone? :)

Comment: But does it work? Mailing list emailz or blog poztz or didn't happen! :)

Comment: Chameleon works fine with Plone. I often use it in production with no problems at all.